# Shifting rolling average in groupby without transform?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, rolling-computation

```
a = df.groupby("RaceID")["wS"].transform(lambda x: x.expanding().mean().shift())
b = df.groupby("RaceID")["wS"].expanding().mean().shift().sort_index(level=1).droplevel(0)
```

I get the correct result if I run the first line. The second approach on the other hand is faster. It works fine as well, if I don't use shift this moves all the values in the rolling average of each group one step ahead.

```
        RaceID  transform   notransform noshift
7140    1021458 0.215909    0.215909    0.191919
7141    1021459 NaN         0.191919    2.375000
7142    1021459 2.375000    2.375000    1.187500
7143    1021459 1.187500    1.187500    0.791667
7144    1021459 0.791667    0.791667    0.593750
7145    1021459 0.593750    0.593750    0.475000
7146    1021459 0.475000    0.475000    0.395833
7147    1021459 0.395833    0.395833    0.339286
7148    1021459 0.339286    0.339286    0.296875
7149    1021460 NaN         0.296875    10.000000
```

The column transform is the result of the first line and no transform is the result of the second line.

As you can see in line with index 7141 the transform correctly sets the first value to NaN when shifting the group. The operation without transform actually shifts the elements correctly, however it sets the first value to the last value of the previous group. This behavior is visible in line with index 1021460.

Data-example:

```
        RaceID  wS
7130    1017734 0.000000
7131    1017734 0.000000
7132    1021458 1.727273
7133    1021458 0.000000
7134    1021458 0.000000
7135    1021458 0.000000
7136    1021458 0.000000
7137    1021458 0.000000
7138    1021458 0.000000
7139    1021458 0.000000
7140    1021458 0.000000
7141    1021459 2.375000
7142    1021459 0.000000
7143    1021459 0.000000
7144    1021459 0.000000
7145    1021459 0.000000
7146    1021459 0.000000
7147    1021459 0.000000
7148    1021459 0.000000
7149    1021460 10.000000
7150    1021460 0.000000
7151    1021460 0.000000
7152    1021460 0.000000
7153    1021460 0.000000
7154    1021460 0.000000
7155    1021460 0.000000
7156    1021460 0.000000
7157    1021460 0.000000
7158    1021460 0.000000
7159    1021460 0.000000
7160    1021460 0.000000
7161    1021460 0.000000
7162    1021460 0.000000
7163    1021460 0.000000
7164    1021460 0.000000
7165    1021460 0.000000
7166    1021460 0.000000
7167    1021461 201.000000
```

Comment: a sample of your input data would be helpful here

Comment: Is your data sorted per raceID like in your example?

Comment: @Ben.T I didn't sort it. I am not sure how this is relevant here.

Comment: you could `mask` the first element of each raceID if they are ordered, because your problem is just that in the second line, the `shift` is not done per group, and with ordered data it is possible to mask the first element of each group

Comment: @Ben.T thanks, it is one solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example the shifting is happening before the return.  In the second it's happening after, so the data is no longer grouped when the shift happens.

You'll probably want to group again after the mean, so that the shift performs groupwise.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'group':[1,1,1,2,2,2], 'values':[1,2,3,10,20,30]})

df.groupby("group", as_index=False)["values"].expanding().mean().groupby(level=0).shift().sort_index(level=1).droplevel(0)
```

Output

```
0     NaN
1     1.0
2     1.5
3     NaN
4    10.0
5    15.0
```

Comment: Thank you, nice solution. Speed doesn't suffer much either, still much faster than transform.